# torch.narrow() with tensor of start indices

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm wondering if it's possible to do something in PyTorch...

Basically, what I'm trying to do is something like `torch.narrow()`, but where the `start` value is a tensor of indices.

Suppose I had the following tensors:

```py
start_indices = [3, 1, 2, ...] # shape: (M,)
dataset = [
    3, 5, 3, 4, 8, 0, 1,
    3, 9, 7, 2, 7, 3, 7,
    6, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 5,
    ...
] # shape: (M, N) (here, N = 7, just for demo)
```

In my use case, `M ~ 10^3` and `N > 10^6`

I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like this:

```py
torch.narrow(
    input=dataset,
    dim=1,
    start=start_indices,
    length=4
)
```

that returns a "narrowed" version of the original dataset, where the start of each row is selected by its corresponding start index. To complete the example I gave above, the result would look like:

```py
result = [
    4, 8, 0, 1,
    9, 7, 2, 7,
    2, 3, 0, 2,
    ....
] # shape: (M, 4)
```

I realize that depending on the start indices and length, you could have some lines going out of bounds of the original tensor -> I'm fine with receiving an error in this case.

Right now, I'm currently using a for-loop to do this, but it becomes far too slow as `M` becomes large. I'm hoping there's a way to do this that takes advantage of data parallelism.

Any ideas? I thought of using `torch.index_select()`, but it only selects within rows based off of single indices. I want to select within rows by single indices, but then *extend* those selections out by some fixed length. In that way, what I'm looking for is kind of a "combination" of `torch.narrow()` and `torch.index_select()`.

Thanks in advance!